# SQL - cartesian product of PARTITIONs

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, graph-theory, recursive-query

There is a really complicated query, which I cannot wrap my head around alone. In the queried table there are 5 columns: `PK_ID`, which is the unique identifier of the value, `ID`, which connects the aggregated values in one group, the `count`, which says, how many value groups should be aggregated (if there aren't enough, the group with such `ID` should be ommited from the query results), the `num`, which says the number of the aggregated value inside the group, and the `value` to be aggregated.

```
(Table T1)

PK_ID |   ID  |  num  |  count |  value
------+-------+-------+--------+--------
 1    |   1   |   1   |   3    |   A
------+-------+-------+--------+--------
 2    |   1   |   2   |   3    |   B
------+-------+-------+--------+--------
 3    |   1   |   3   |   3    |   C
------+-------+-------+--------+--------
 4    |   1   |   1   |   3    |   D
------+-------+-------+--------+--------
 5    |   1   |   3   |   3    |   E
------+-------+-------+--------+--------
 6    |   1   |   2   |   3    |   F
------+-------+-------+--------+--------
 7    |   1   |   3   |   3    |   G
------+-------+-------+--------+--------
 8    |   2   |   1   |   2    |   H
------+-------+-------+--------+--------
 9    |   2   |   2   |   2    |   I
------+-------+-------+--------+--------
 10   |   2   |   1   |   2    |   J
------+-------+-------+--------+--------
 11   |   3   |   1   |   5    |   X
```

The results of such query would be:

```
PK_ID | T1_ID | cross_aggr | T1_PK_IDs
------+-------+------------+-----------
  1   |   1   | {A, B, C}  | {1, 2, 3}
------+-------+------------+-----------
  2   |   1   | {A, B, E}  | {1, 2, 5}
------+-------+------------+-----------
  3   |   1   | {A, B, G}  | {1, 2, 7}
------+-------+------------+-----------
  4   |   1   | {A, F, C}  | {1, 6, 3}
------+-------+------------+-----------
  5   |   1   | {A, F, E}  | {1, 6, 5}
------+-------+------------+-----------
  6   |   1   | {A, F, G}  | {1, 6, 7}
------+-------+------------+-----------
  7   |   1   | {D, B, C}  | {4, 2, 3}
------+-------+------------+-----------
  8   |   1   | {D, B, E}  | {4, 2, 5}
------+-------+------------+-----------
  9   |   1   | {D, B, G}  | {4, 2, 7}
------+-------+------------+-----------
  10  |   1   | {D, F, C}  | {4, 6, 3}
------+-------+------------+-----------
  11  |   1   | {D, F, E}  | {4, 6, 5}
------+-------+------------+-----------
  12  |   1   | {D, F, G}  | {4, 6, 7}
------+-------+------------+-----------
  13  |   2   | {H, I}     | {8, 9}
------+-------+------------+-----------
  14  |   2   | {J, I}     | {10, 9}
```

So it returned every possible combination of `value`s inside each group, defined by `ID` and described by `count`, and those values are aggregated in the order of each individual `num`.

It looks like I have to use the `CROSS JOIN` (in the same manner as the cartesian product would work in linear algebra), but the `CROSS JOIN` seems to work only if the number of `JOIN`ed tables is known beforehand, but there is the `count` complication. The `count` itself could potentially (I mean it doesn't but it could) range from `2` to `infinity`.

I have thought of having it processed by a `WINDOW` function, `PARTITION BY` the `ID` and by `num`, but after that I'm stuck, since there seems no way to have a cartesian product of those partitions.

Should I call it a day and find another way to process the data, or is there a way to compose such a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reads like a graph-walking problem - which requires a recursive query.

```
with recursive cte as (
    select id, num, cnt, 1 as lvl,
        array[value::text] as arr_values, 
        array[pk_id::int] as arr_pk_id
    from mytable where num = 1
    union all
    select c.id, t.num, c.cnt, c.lvl + 1, 
        c.arr_values || t.value::text, 
        c.arr_pk_id  || t.pk_id
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t 
        on  t.id = c.id 
        and t.num = c.num + 1 
        and t.num <= c.cnt
)
select id, arr_values, arr_pk_id 
from cte 
where array_length(arr_pk_id, 1) = cnt
order by arr_pk_id
```

For each `id`, the recursive query sarts at `num` `1` and follows all possible paths. The outer query just filters on the end of paths.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4fb00e9dcf2e23e685cd9a124106c5b6)**:

```
id | arr_values | arr_pk_id
-: | :--------- | :--------
 1 | {A,B,C}    | {1,2,3}  
 1 | {A,B,E}    | {1,2,5}  
 1 | {A,B,G}    | {1,2,7}  
 1 | {A,F,C}    | {1,6,3}  
 1 | {A,F,E}    | {1,6,5}  
 1 | {A,F,G}    | {1,6,7}  
 1 | {D,B,C}    | {4,2,3}  
 1 | {D,B,E}    | {4,2,5}  
 1 | {D,B,G}    | {4,2,7}  
 1 | {D,F,C}    | {4,6,3}  
 1 | {D,F,E}    | {4,6,5}  
 1 | {D,F,G}    | {4,6,7}  
 2 | {H,I}      | {8,9}    
 2 | {J,I}      | {10,9}
```

Comment: bro sorry, was dbfiddling the thing. I can't believe it really is possible, it seems there is so much I don't know about SQL, that's why it seems so limiting for the many. But when such guys like yourself come into the game, the potential of the language is taken to the fullest. Thank you a ton, you deserve far more reputation than I can give you with my +1.